# Why does Vim align indentation to parentheses/colon?

Tags: vim

I've run into an unusual indentation issue in Vim that I'd like to understand better. The lines below describe what I'm typing:

```
writing some words 
  manually indenting this line 
  this line got automatically indented 
  here's a line with a colon: some more words 
  this line is indented as expected 
  now I introduce (parentheses) and nothing happens 
  indented as expected
  here it comes (parentheses and a colon): let the magic begin
                                           why do parentheses+colon indent me to here?
```

Why does it do this, and how can I make it stop? :) I like cindent overall, so I'd prefer to keep that over autoindent/smartindent.

My Vim settings are:

- Empty ~/.vimrc except for :set cindent expandtab
- All plugins disabled
- `:verbose set ft? ai? si? cindent? indentkeys? cinkeys? cinoptions? indentexpr? formatoptions?`

  ```
    filetype=
  noautoindent
  nosmartindent
    cindent
    indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
    cinkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
    cinoptions=
    indentexpr=
    formatoptions=tcq
          Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/debian.vim line 3
  ```

Comment: `cindent` is for C/C++. It absolutely should not be used for some random stuff, as it can produce random results. If still curious, see [this Q&A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/is-it-possible-to-get-the-rule-cinoptions-that-govern-the-indentation-for-a-sp) and make experiments yourself.

Comment: Hmm, pity; looks like I can't really pick and choose parts of its behavior then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Back to autoindent/smartindent it is then.

Comment: You can write a custom function to calc an indent of your own (`:h indent-expression`). But, 1) It'd better aim some specific filetype (`:h 30.3`), as creating "the one-to-fit-everything" is almost impossible; 2) You have to know VimScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt mentioned, you probably don't want to use `cindent` for things that aren't C or C-like languages, since it has a lot of hardcoded knowledge about C syntax that isn't generally applicable to text, or even to other programming languages like Python or Ruby.

What you can do is something like this:

```
" For general usage.
set autoindent

autocmd FileType c  setl cindent noautoindent
```

That will use `autoindent` for things that are not C, but `cindent` for C.  If you use other languages, you can add additional stanzas for `cpp`, `java`, etc.  You can also use this type of `autocmd` statement to do things like adjusting indent levels (via `ts`, `sts`, and `sw`) or switching between tabs and spaces, depending on the norms of the language you're using (e.g., Ruby's 2 spaces or Go's 8-space tabs).

For text, you may also want to adjust `formatlistpat` to adjust what constitutes a list header, which when automatic indentation is enabled, determines whether the next line should be indented to continue the list.  It's possible that's part of what's going on here.  The value I use for that option is `^[.-*+•]\\+\\s\\+`, which shouldn't cause the colon to be considered.